# Adding unique column values to userform combobox that is sorted alphabetically

Tags: vba

Hi I'm trying to add unique values from three columns to three different comboboxes. I also wish to use arrays and for loops so it loops three times for each column.The three comboboxes are named, cmbTruck; cmbSource; and cmbDest, and wish to input values from column, 2; 16; and 16 again, respectively, from the 2nd row to the last entry.

```
Dim cel As Range
Dim rngItems As Range
Dim oDictionary As Object
Dim arr As Variant
Dim cmbOptions As Variant
Dim i as long
Dim lrow As Long


arr = array(2, 16, 16)
cmbOptions = Array(cmbTruck, cmbSource, cmbDest)

lrow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = LBound(arr) to UBound(arr)

With cmbOptions(i)
    Set oDictionary = createobject("Scripting.Dictionary") 
    Set rngItems = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, arr(i)), Cells(lrow, 2))

    For Each cel In rngItems
        If oDictionary.exists(cel.Value) Then
        'Do Nothing
        Else
            oDictionary.Add cel.Value, 0
            .AddItem cel.Value
        End If
    Next cel
End With

Next i
```

I am getting an error '424' Object required on Line17. I think this is caused by the cmbOptions array and the with loop line with cmbOptions not recognizing as a  comboboxname. Could I get assistance on this, would be greatly appreciated.

Jae

Comment: You need to use the `Set` keyword to assign to a `Range`:  `Set rg = ws.Range(arr(1), Range(arr(1).End(xlDown)))`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Made some changes now and having trouble with the array containing combobox names.